# can't understand the code that shedskin generates

Tags: c++, python, converters

for example I have a function in python that I want to convert to c++ (or call from c++ but I don't want to depend on python interpretor)
simple python function

```
//test.py
def my_sum(x,y):
    print "Hello World!"
    return x*x+y
```

I run shedskin and have

```
//test.cpp
#include "builtin.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"

namespace __test__ {


str *__name__;



void __init() {
    __name__ = new str("__main__");

}

} // module namespace

int main(int, char **) {
    __shedskin__::__init();
    __shedskin__::__start(__test__::__init);
}

//test.hpp
#ifndef __TEST_HPP
#define __TEST_HPP

using namespace __shedskin__;
namespace __test__ {



extern str *__name__;



} // module namespace
#endif
```

ugly code and there is no my function my_sum and code depends on "builtin.hpp". is it possible to convert only function?

or

I want to call function from my c++ code something like 
int sum= py.my_sum(3,5);
how can I do this?

or

maybe I can do DLL or Lib from python code that I can use in c++ code?

Comment: The only thing we currently know of that can reliably translate code from one language to another is a human being.

Comment: @geekosaur: Ever heard of compilers?

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer, turn down the pedanticism filter, please.  For that matter, there are translators from some languages to some other languages (e.g. Fortran to C) that aren't too horrid... but general Python to C++ is not going to be pretty, as shown by this question.

Comment: @geekosaur: I know that is a hard task.
can you answer practically to the question? all the more so question have alternatives in implementations(not only code convertion by shedskin,by the way i find out it does't work on real code,too much restrictions)

Comment: @mrgloom, I'm afraid I did answer you practically.  As did the shedskin documentation, by pointing out its restrictions.  You can call out to Python from your C++; you can use [Cython](http://cython.org/) to turn it inside out and invoke C/C++ from Python; you cannot in the general case turn arbitrary Python to C++ in any sensible way.

Comment: @geekosaur: It was not clear to me from your first comment that you meant "pretty code".

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer, the question shows the kind of code you can expect from translation attempts, and complains about it; clearly it's not looking for non-"pretty" code.

Comment: @geekosaur -- Yes, but I was commenting on your "*reliably* translate code from one language to another".  So it was just a misunderstanding on my side, apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice the warning that shedskin gives for this program:

```
*WARNING* test.py:1: function my_sum not called!
```

it is also mentioned in the documentation that for compilation to work, a function should be called (directly or indirectly), as it's not possible to do type inference otherwise.. how to determine the types of the arguments of my_sum, if there's not even a single call to it..? :-)

adding this, for example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  my_sum(1,1)
```

makes my_sum appear in the generated C++ code, which can potentially be called from another C++ program.

Comment: thanks, you answered correct to my question,not like others. But it still unclear how in this case shedskin determines type of arguments? (1,1)  can be float,int,double.

Comment: a single python function becomes a single C++ function, with types deduced from how the function is used. in this case it is only used with integers, so it will become integer-based. if you want a float-based version, use (1.0, 1.0). it will also accept integers then, but will always return a float (since that's the deduced return type).